# Laravel 5.5 laravel-echo-server.json configuration over https and socket.io.js location on same domain

Tags: laravel-5

My entire laravel-echo-server.json looks like as below

```
{
    "authHost": "https://example.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "created using command laravel-echo-server init",
            "key": "created using command laravel-echo-server init"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
        "host": "example.com ip address",
        "port": 6379
       },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "https",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "/home/username/ssl/certs/XXX..XX.crt",
    "sslKeyPath": "/home/username/ssl/keys/XXX...XX.key",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

Pieces of code in 'public/js/app.js':

```
window.Echo = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_laravel_echo__["a" /* default */]({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

laravel-echo-server start and redis-cli monitor are working also fine.

But in browser(inspect element), http://example.com:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MZ29tzO return no response.

Server: Cent OS 7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

- you've installed `npm install --save socket.io-client` and `npm install --save laravel-echo`
- the port 6001 is open

I've followed [this instructions and customized some configurations](https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d#59d8). Take a look at [my laravel-echo-server.json working on LOCAL enviroment](https://gist.github.com/cawecoy/31c00cd38b963357d1c614eee6ff321b) and [this laravel-echo-server.json working on PRODUCTION enviroment](https://gist.github.com/cawecoy/dee1b1b07db42c22519286787e256c3e), it should give you insights.